# Magento 1.7 - installer script does not run

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

My installer script does not run.

/app/etc/modules/Starmall_Salesorder.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Starmall_Salesorder>
        <active>true</active>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Starmall_Salesorder>
</modules>
```

Config.xml

```
<modules>
    <Starmall_Salesorder>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Starmall_Salesorder>
</modules>

...
    <resources>
        <starmall_salesorder_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Starmall_Salesorder</module>
            </setup>
        </starmall_salesorder_setup>
    </resources>

...
```

/app/code/local/Starmall/Salesorder/sql/starmall_salesorder_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php:

```
<?php echo 'Running installer: '.get_class($this)."\n <br /> \n";  
die("Exit for now");
```

When loading a page I don't see the test output.
There is no row in `core_resource` for this module.

No errors to see in /var/log

Why does this installer not run?

I added debug line in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php`
It doesn't get here in this function `_installResourceDb($newVersion)`

```
    protected function _installResourceDb($newVersion)
{
    Mage::log("this line is not added to log file");

    $oldVersion = $this->_modifyResourceDb(self::TYPE_DB_INSTALL, '', $newVersion);
    $this->_modifyResourceDb(self::TYPE_DB_UPGRADE, $oldVersion, $newVersion);
    $this->_getResource()->setDbVersion($this->_resourceName, $newVersion);

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: 1) Verify that config cache is disabled or at least that it is being cleared. 2) Post your module's declaration file (located in *app/etc/modules/*).

Comment: I have added my `/app/etc/modules/Starmall_Salesorder.xml`  I have cache disabled and deleted to be sure the /var folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a module declaration file with a `modules` node matching your post, and that you are on a case-sensitive filesystem, then the application is not loading your module configuration file.

When Magento is initializing, the children nodes of `<modules>` are used along with the `codePool` values as part of the path to each module's configuration file. The node name (e.g. `starmall_salesorder`) is converted to the directory path *Starmall/Salesorder* (note the uppercasing). To resolve this, correct the node name for your module in both the declaration and configuration files to be `Starmall_Salesorder` and also change the value of `global/resources/starmall_salesorder_setup/setup/module` to match.

One further note: in Magento CE 1.6 and higher the model layer was reworked to be database-agnostic, so it is appropriate for new modules intended for 1.6+ to use install filenames such as *install-1.0.php* for backend-agnostic upgrade scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Today I have had some trouble with this as well. I had to clear the cache, even though it was disabled. So whenever updating/changing/running your installer script, make sure you first clear your cache manually.